# Running Linux in a Virtual Machine on ARM

Tags: macos, virtualization

I am following the [Running Linux in a Virtual Machine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/virtualization/creating_and_running_a_linux_virtual_machine) guide on MacOS 14 w/ ARM. Fedora kernel and RAM disk images were acquired [here](https://mirror.fcix.net/fedora/linux/releases/39/Everything/aarch64/os/images/pxeboot/).

I opened `LinuxVirtualMachine.xcodeproj` from the example; selecting 'LinuxVirtualMachine' under 'Targets', and navigating to 'Signing and Capabilities', I linked my Personal Team (needed to connect my Apple ID) under 'Signing->Team'. Clicking 'run' outputs the following:

```
Usage: /Users/shea/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LinuxVirtualMachine-baalsbzvoxxbspgicozzllxbyqmh/Build/Products/Debug/LinuxVirtualMachine <kernel-path> <initial-ramdisk-path>
Program ended with exit code: 64
```

So I execute the following in Terminal from a directory containing the two images from Fedora:

```
% /Users/shea/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LinuxVirtualMachine-baalsbzvoxxbspgicozzllxbyqmh/Build/Products/Debug/LinuxVirtualMachine ./vmlinuz ./initrd.img
```

And receive the output:

```
Failed to start the virtual machine. Error Domain=VZErrorDomain Code=1 "The virtual machine failed to start." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailure=Internal Virtualization error., NSLocalizedFailureReason=The virtual machine failed to start.}
```

An old thread on the [developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/709539) seems to imply this may be because the kernel image used to be compressed but is no longer? Another commenter suggests it is because `vmlinuz`is a gz file and to extract it, but `file vmlinuz`outputs `vmlinuz: PE32+ executable (EFI application) Aarch64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows` and `gzip` won't work even with the .gz extension. Did I miss a step?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this as a developer wanting to discover how to spawn Linux VMs? Or is the purpose to run Linux? In either case, you could be using ready made apps like VirtualBuddy which is open source.

Comment: @Gilby VirtualBuddy made installing the Ubuntu Server's ARM ISO a breeze. is there any way to have VirtualBuddy run the VM in a Terminal instance/other emulators (allowing for scrolling)? or is that not a part of the Virtualization framework?

Comment: AFAIK, it is a virtual screen only. But Ubuntu Server should allow SSH which would get it running in Terminal/iTerm. You need to experiment, but I would expect it to work so long as the VM is using a bridged network (i.e. on same subnet as your Mac). I am yet to run a Linux VM in VirtualBuddy - I have only tried macOS VMs.